# Match a specific number in a line

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In a line like this

> size: 421,939,100 bytes

I have to know only if the number is a `0`. In particular, I'm interested only in how to use `grep` to do this task.

Many thanks!

Comment: `grep 'size:' yourfile | cut -d":" -f2` or `awk '$1=="size:"{print $2}' yourfile` would likely do the trick if you're down with using `awk`.

Comment: For this particular case, just grep `[1-9]`. If it is not 0, then, there must be another digit somewhere.

Comment: you stated you tried a regex and got nothing satisfactory; please update the question with your regex code attempt(s) and the (wrong) result(s) generated by your code

Comment: @JNevill thnak you for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you go the direct approach?

```
echo size: 421,939,100 bytes | grep -q "size: 0 bytes" && echo "Zero bytes"
```

Answer (score 0):

A  ' ' ( " ") followed by a '0' ("0") followed by zero or more '0's (0{0,}) followed by zero or 1 '.' (.{0,1}) followed by zero or more '0's (0{0,}) followed by a ' ' ( " "):

```
Mac_3.2.57$echo "size: 0 bytes" | grep ' 00\{0,\}\.\{0,1\}0\{0,\} '
size: 0 bytes
Mac_3.2.57$echo "size: 000 bytes" | grep ' 00\{0,\}\.\{0,1\}0\{0,\} '
size: 000 bytes
Mac_3.2.57$echo "size: 0. bytes" | grep ' 00\{0,\}\.\{0,1\}0\{0,\} '
size: 0. bytes
Mac_3.2.57$echo "size: 0.0 bytes" | grep ' 00\{0,\}\.\{0,1\}0\{0,\} '
size: 0.0 bytes
Mac_3.2.57$echo "size: 0.0000 bytes" | grep ' 00\{0,\}\.\{0,1\}0\{0,\} '
size: 0.0000 bytes
Mac_3.2.57$echo "size: 00000.0000 bytes" | grep ' 00\{0,\}\.\{0,1\}0\{0,\} '
size: 00000.0000 bytes
Mac_3.2.57$echo "size: 00000.0001 bytes" | grep ' 00\{0,\}\.\{0,1\}0\{0,\} '
Mac_3.2.57$echo "size: 2 bytes" | grep ' 00\{0,\}\.\{0,1\}0\{0,\} '
Mac_3.2.57$
```